# Parsing nested JSON with lists and dicts to separate dataframes for each

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My JSON consists of dictionary as well as lists.

I want to write the dictionary and the lists to a separate dataframes as below:

Here's a sample JSON, I have thousands similar to these:

```
{
  "zone_id" : "1001",
  "timezone" : "Eastern Time",
  "address" : {
    "city" : "Niagara Falls",
    "country_code" : "US"
  },
  "financial" : {
    "currency" : {
      "code" : "USA"
    }
  },
  "amenities" : {
    "self_park" : true,
    "paved" : true,
    "mobile_pass" : null,
    "handicap" : null
  },
  "description" : "",
  "html_description" : null,
  "reserve" : false,
  "access_type" : "mobile_pay",
  "product_types" : [ "ondemand" ],
  "rates" : [ {
    "id" : 50000.1,
    "rate_type" : "valid_for",
    "zone_id" : "1001",
    "description" : "1 Hour",
    "price" : "1.50"
  }, {
    "id" : 50001.1,
    "rate_type" : "valid_for",
    "zone_id" : "1001",
    "description" : "4 Hours",
    "price" : "3.00"
  }, {
    "id" : 50002.1,
    "rate_type" : "valid_for",
    "zone_id" : "1001",
    "description" : "8 Hours",
    "price" : "6.00"
  }],
  "reservation_configuration" : null,
  "company" : {
    "proper_name" : "Niagara Falls",
    "logo_thumbnail" : null,
    "unique" : "niagarafalls"
  }
}
```

I want to flatten the json into following dataframes which have these columns and corresponding data:

```
df1:
    zone_id,
    timezone,
    description,
    html_description,
    reserve,
    access_type,
    product_types,
    rates,
    reservation_configuration,
    address.city,
    address.country_code,
    financial.currency.code,
    amenities.self_park,
    amenities.paved,
    amenities.mobile_pass,
    amenities.handicap,
    company.proper_name,
    company.logo_thumbnail,
    company.unique

address:
    zone_id
    city
    country_code
    
financial.currency:
    zone_id
    code
    
amenities:
    zone_id
    self_park
    paved
    mobile_pass
    handicap
    
product_types:
    zone_id
    product_types

rates:
    id
    rate_type
    zone_id
    description
    price
    
company:
    zone_id
    proper_name
    logo_thumbnail
    unique
```

This is what I have done so far, I am able to produce `df1` with that, but I am unable to separate the lists/ dicts within the json into dataframes, with a key attached to each data frame; `zone_id` being the unique identifier(akin to the primary key of the table in a table in a database) for each, for future dataframe joining purposes. The `product_types` and `rates` have information which is being missed with how I am trying to solve this. I need help with spitting each dictionary or list into separate dataframes, with the `zone_id` attached with each.

```
dfs = []

for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    print(index, js)
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.load(json_file)
        a = pd.json_normalize(json_text)
        dfs.append(a)
        
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're main problem is that you're trying to normalize the JSON while you're reading it. Sometimes this can work, but in your case you'll need the actual nested fields to construct the different dataframes.

This should do what you want:

```py
import json
import pandas
import itertools


# Your data
raw_data = """{
    "zone_id": "1001",
    "timezone": "Eastern Time",
    "address": {"city": "Niagara Falls", "country_code": "US"},
    "financial": {"currency": {"code": "USA"}},
    "amenities": {
        "self_park": true,
        "paved": true,
        "mobile_pass": null,
        "handicap": null
    },
    "description": "",
    "html_description": null,
    "reserve": false,
    "access_type": "mobile_pay",
    "product_types": ["ondemand"],
    "rates": [
        {
            "id": 50000.1,
            "rate_type": "valid_for",
            "zone_id": "1001",
            "description": "1 Hour",
            "price": "1.50"
        },
        {
            "id": 50001.1,
            "rate_type": "valid_for",
            "zone_id": "1001",
            "description": "4 Hours",
            "price": "3.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 50002.1,
            "rate_type": "valid_for",
            "zone_id": "1001",
            "description": "8 Hours",
            "price": "6.00"
        }
    ],
    "reservation_configuration": null,
    "company": {
        "proper_name": "Niagara Falls",
        "logo_thumbnail": null,
        "unique": "niagarafalls"
    }
}
"""
data = json.loads(raw_data)

# Lets pretend we have multiple
data = [data] * 100


# NOTE: You will probably want to use something like this (remove the comments to use it):
# data = []
# for json_file_path in json_files:
#     with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, json_file_path)) as json_file:
#         data.append(json.load(json_file))

# =========
# Construct the different types of dataframes

# df1
df1_columns = [
    "zone_id",
    "timezone",
    "description",
    "html_description",
    "reserve",
    "access_type",
    "product_types",
    "rates",
    "reservation_configuration",
    "address.city",
    "address.country_code",
    "financial.currency.code",
    "amenities.self_park",
    "amenities.paved",
    "amenities.mobile_pass",
    "amenities.handicap",
    "company.proper_name",
    "company.logo_thumbnail",
    "company.unique",
]
df1 = pandas.json_normalize(data)[df1_columns]

# Address
address = pandas.DataFrame([{"zone_id": row["zone_id"], **row["address"]} for row in data])

# financial_currency
financial_currency = pandas.DataFrame([{"zone_id": row["zone_id"], **row["financial"]["currency"]} for row in data])

# amenities
amenities = pandas.DataFrame([{"zone_id": row["zone_id"], **row["amenities"]} for row in data])

# product_types
product_types = pandas.DataFrame([{"zone_id": row["zone_id"], "product_types": row["product_types"]} for row in data])

# rates
rates = pandas.DataFrame(itertools.chain.from_iterable([row["rates"] for row in data]))

# company
company = pandas.DataFrame([{"zone_id": row["zone_id"], **row["company"]} for row in data])
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, while I check if it works for me, I wanted to mention that the column names in each of the separate dataframes is not a fixed list, some JSONs, can have more keys as compared to another, while others may not have all the keys, how would I deal with the dynamic column names?

Comment: Also, because the keys within each list/ dictionary may or may not be consistent through the JSONs, I want to be able to fetch the key names for column dataframes from the JSONs itself, instead of hard coding them, is that possible?

Comment: the solution you have provided does not seem to produce what I am looking for.

Comment: @cyrus24, so you want a dynamic format that magically transforms into something structured? No, that's impossible. You'll have to specify the format of your dataframes at some point. You can have it include all field within a section of your JSON (`**row["company"]`). Please give an example of the output you're looking for, to me it looks like I'm matching your request exactly.